# Get number of additions that lead to a specific sum with given summands

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have $n$ variables. Each of these variables (e.g. $a$) have their own interval between $0$ and $a_i$ (whole numbers). The only rule is that all these variables have to add up to a given value $s$.

An example:
$n = 3$, so the three variables are $a$, $b$ and $c$
$a_i = 2$, so $0\le$ $a$ $\le2$
$b_i = 3$, so $0\le$ $b$ $\le3$
$c_i = 4$, so $0\le$ $c$ $\le4$
$s = 6$, so $a+b+c=6$

The 9 unique possible solutions for these given variables are the following (the order of the variables is still important, so solution 7 and solution 9 are not the same):
$a=0$    $b=2$    $c=4$
$a=0$    $b=3$    $c=3$
$a=1$    $b=1$    $c=4$
$a=1$    $b=2$    $c=3$
$a=1$    $b=3$    $c=2$
$a=2$    $b=0$    $c=4$
$a=2$    $b=1$    $c=3$
$a=2$    $b=2$    $c=2$
$a=2$    $b=3$    $c=1$

What is the correct formula or program to only get the *number* of unique, possible solutions for any value of $n$, $s$ and the other variables, which would be 9 in this case?

Comment: Generating functions are your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have $k$ variables, and you want to add it up to $n$:
$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1-x^{a_i+1}}{1-x}$$

Then your solution is $f(0)$.

To come up with this, start with the generating functions for your constraints:
$$(1+x+...x^{a_i}) = \frac{1-x^{a_i+1}}{1-x}$$
Suppose we compute part of this product with your example:
$$(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$$
Then multiply the $x$ from the first by the $x^2$ in the second and the $x^3$ in the last. This gives $x^6$, and corresponds to the $a=1,b=2,c=3$ solution.

Then coefficient of $x^n$ in that product is the number of solutions. I used the derivative and factorial, then evaluation at $x=0$ to get this, but if you're using a CAS it probably has a more efficient coefficient function.

Answer (score 0):

Let me work out for this particular case. You should be able to put it into a formula.

If you can't, I'll see later.

We can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) with inclusion-exclusion.

Without any restrictions, there are ${6+3-1\choose 3-1} = {8\choose 2}= 28$ solutions.

To subtract cases that violate, (say) the $a_i$ restriction, pre-place $(2+1)=3$ in the $a_i$ compartment, and so on, then for combos of two, and combos of three, *if possible*, so

$${8\choose2} - \left[{5\choose 2} + {4\choose 2} + {3\choose 2}\right] = 9$$

Here it was not possible to violate constraints for combos of 2 or 3, but suppose we raise *s* to 16, then we would have

$${18\choose2} - \left[{15\choose 2} + {14\choose 2} + {13\choose 2}\right] + \left[{11\choose 2} + {10\choose 2} + {9\choose 2}\right] - \left[{6\choose 2}\right]$$

Comment: This looks like a great answer, but sorry, I don't really know how to put this into a formula.

Comment: You can see how to put into a formula at example PIE 2 at http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/PIE.pdf

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot, but I still don't understand how you 'convert' this: $|A|+|B|+|C| - |A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap\text{C}|$ (from one of the first lines of the document about PIE) into the last formula in your answer. A more specific example would be how you convert $|A|$ into $15\choose 2$, $|A\cap B|$ into $11\choose 2$ or $|A\cap B\cap\text{C}|$ into $6\choose 2$.

Comment: Since $|A|$ can't exceed 2, we pre-place 3 so that all such solutions become unacceptable, sum now needed reduces by3, and ${18\choose 2}$ becomes ${15\choose 2}$. Similarly, $|A\cap B|$ can't exceed $2+3$, we pre-place $3+4=7$, sum now needed reduces by 7, and ${18\choose 2}$ reduces to ${11\choose 2}$, and so on.